# The type or namespace name 'MD5CryptoServiceProvider' does not exist

Tags: windows, visual-studio, windows-phone-8

I am using the code for generating the MD5 hash in my code ... i do not know why namespace error is given by the compiler. am including the (using System.Security.Cryptography)
Am new to windows phone app development need a little bit help.

```
System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider x = new System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
```

Here the error is on MD5CryptoServiceProvider()..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MD5CryptoServiceProvider isn't available in Silverlight.

[MSDN : Silverlight System.Security.Cryptography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography(v=vs.95).aspx)

You have a few choices though.

> - Use another hash algorithm that Silverlight supports in WP8 (probably the best, since md5 is pretty outdated)
> - Upgrade to WP8.1 runtime (universal) and use Windows.Security.Cryptography and
>     Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core
> - Program your own, it's a pretty simple algorithm. :)
> - Use someone else implementation.

---

[Jitesh Upadhyay complete MD5 Implementation Windows Phone](http://upadhyayjitesh.blogspot.com/2013/01/windows-phone-md5-hash-conversion.html)